Errror when adding event listener to the status btns of a LS todo project
the html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css"
        />
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                background: #032a7e;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100vh;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            #main {
                width: 350px;
                max-width: 95%;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
                gap: 3rem;
            }

            h2 {
                margin-top: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 1.8;
                color: white;
            }

            .todo {
                /* background: #030e27; */
                padding: 10px 20px;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #888;
                color: #fff;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                height: 45px;
                font-size: 0.875rem;
                transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
            }

            .todo:first-child {
                border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
            }

            .todo:last-child {
                border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom: 0;
            }

            #info-input {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }

            input {
                width: calc(100% - 50px);
                padding: 10px 20px;
                height: 40px;
                background: #222;
                border: 0;
                border-radius: 5px;
                color: #fff;

                &:focus {
                    outline: none;
                }

                &::placeholder {
                    color: #666;
                }
            }

            .adder-button {
                height: 40px;
                width: 40px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                border: 0;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background: rgb(63, 138, 243);
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 1.25rem;
                margin-bottom: 3rem;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .bi-trash,
            .bi-x-circle,
            .bi-check-circle {
                transition: 0.2s ease-in-out color;
            }

            .bi-trash:hover,
            .bi-x-circle:hover,
            .bi-check-circle:hover {
                color: orange;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .icons-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: flex-end;
                align-items: center;
                gap: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Todos Mananger | ❤️</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h2>
                Things <span style="color: royalblue">you</span> want to do...
            </h2>
            <div class="todos-container"></div>
            <div id="info-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Task" maxlength="20" minlength="1"/>
                <button class="adder-button"><i class="bi bi-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


and the javascript code:
function _q(p) {
    return document.querySelector(p);
}
function _qa(p) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(p);
}
const todosList = _q(".todos-container");
const info = _q("input");
const adder = _q(".adder-button");
const iconTrash = `<i class="bi bi-trash"></i>`;
let i;
let trashIcons;
let todos;
let todoStatus;
let newObj;
let todoToRemove;
let todoToModify;
let statusBtns;
let alreadyExists;


// function to order the ids of the todo objects in the localstorage when a todo is eliminated
function todosUpdater() {
    todosSelector();
    i = 0;
    todos.forEach((todo) => {
        todo.id = i;
        i++;
    });
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

// function to save "todos" array(from localstorage) in todos variable
function todosSelector() {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
}

// function to select trash icons
function trashIconSelector() {
    trashIcons = _qa(".bi-trash");
}

//function to set an event listener for each trash icon
function trashIconHandler() {
    trashIcons.forEach((trashIcon) => {
        trashIcon.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            todosSelector();
            todoToRemove = todos.findIndex((todo) => {
                return todo.id == e.target.parentElement.dataset.id;
            });
            todos.splice(todoToRemove, 1);
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            todosUpdater();
        });
    });
}


// function to set event listener for status buttons and to program them
// the error happens when calling this function back***********
function statusBtnsEventSetter() {
    statusBtns = _qa("i:last-child");
    statusBtns.forEach((statusBtn) => {
        statusBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            todosSelector();
            todoToModify = todos.findIndex((todo) => {
                return (
                    todo.id == e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id
                );
            });
            todoStatus = todos[todoToModify].completed == true ? true : false;
            if (todoStatus) {
                todos[todoToModify].completed = false;
                e.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.background =
                    "#041a48";
                e.target.className = "bi-check-circle";
            } else {
                todos[todoToModify].completed = true;
                e.target.parentElement.parentElement.style.background =
                    "#057719";
                e.target.className = "bi-x-circle";
            }
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
        });
    });
}

// function to add localstorage todos to DOM
function initializer() {
    info.value = "";
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify([]));
    } else {
        todosSelector();
        i = 0;
        todos.forEach((todo) => {
            todoStatus = todo.completed == true ? true : false;
            if (!todoStatus) {
                todosList.innerHTML +=
                    `<div data-id="` +
                    i +
                    `" class="todo" style="background: #041a48;">` +
                    todo.name +
                    `<div class="icons-container">` +
                    iconTrash +
                    `<i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>` +
                    `</div>` +
                    `</div>`;
            } else {
                todosList.innerHTML +=
                    `<div data-id="` +
                    i +
                    `" class="todo" style="background: #057719;">` +
                    todo.name +
                    `<div class="icons-container">` +
                    iconTrash +
                    `<i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i>` +
                    `</div>` +
                    `</div>`;
            }
            i++;
        });
        statusBtnsEventSetter();
        trashIconSelector();
        trashIconHandler();
    }
}

// event listeners:

window.addEventListener("load", initializer);

adder.addEventListener("click", () => {
    todosSelector();
    alreadyExists = todos.some((todo) => {
        return todo.name == info.value.trim();
    });
    if (
        info.value.trim().length > 1 &&
        info.value.trim().length <= 20 &&
        !alreadyExists
    ) {
        (function (txt) {
            txt = info.value.trim();
            i = todos.length;
            newObj = { id: i, name: txt, completed: false };
            todos.push(newObj);
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
            todosList.innerHTML +=
                `<div data-id="` +
                i +
                `" class="todo" style="background: #041a48;">` +
                txt +
                `<div class="icons-container">` +
                iconTrash +
                `<i class="bi bi-check-circle"></i>` +
                `</div>` +
                `</div>`;
            // priority may need to be changed
            statusBtnsEventSetter();
            trashIconSelector();
            trashIconHandler();
        }());
    }
});

it's a todo project which has to be saved in localStoraege in which you could add todos, remove them, and change their status(whether they're completed or not).
the code works fine before you try to add a new todo. I mean suppose you want to work with your current todos; It's just FINE but as soon as you try to add a new todo, you face an error telling that the "todoToModify" variable is -1 which means the findIndex method fails to return the appropriate value for todoToModify.
-the todo gets added to the DOM but when you refresh, the initializer loads the todos in a wrong way(check what i said with multiple todos added, removed or having the status changed).
please run and review the code to see what happens.
I can't think of anything else working wrong. The main problem is the statusBtnsEventSetter function.
at first the status changer was in a way that you could change it by simply clicking on the todo box itself. I added the status buttons because I wondered if the error was because of parenting when adding event listeners. But it didn't help.

Can't reproduce. https://jsfiddle.net/dcvx7so3/ - it loads the previously saved items, when I re-run the fiddle, and I still can add new items afterwards. So where exactly is the error / problem supposed to be?

please run somewhere which allows to check the console. looks you can't see the icons to work with. right?

Fiddle with the BS icons included: https://jsfiddle.net/zdng75ch/ The error appears to occur, when trying to add an already existing item (same text) again. Logging to console shows, that inside your todos.findIndex callback, e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id is always undefined.

that's not the problem. I've already limited the input with alreadyExists var

The error occurs even when I am adding a new item that doesn't already exist. Clicking the "+" button invokes your statusBtn click handler, before the adder click handler.

But as it shows the adder click handler is executed beforehand.  please help me fix that @C3roe

"But as it shows the adder click handler is executed beforehand." - it isn't, as logging to console right at the start of each of the two callback functions shows: https://jsfiddle.net/mtyxdwpz/

So do you have any solutions sir?

In your statusBtnsEventSetter, "i:last-child" gives the adder button(+) too. So, I added an empty div after bi-plus icon in the adder-buttonand it started working. Something like: . The :last-child selector selects all elements that are the last child of their parent. So, you have to exclude the add button.

Thank you! @SoftwareDveloper, that was the smallest thing I could think of!
